# Time complexity of Big O notation

Tags: data-structures, big-o

I need to find the time complexity of some function, And I don’t really sure that I’m right.

Lets see:

```java
f(int i){
    Int x = 1;
    While(x > i){
        System.out.println(x);
        x=x*2;
    }

    While(x > 2){
        x = (int) Math.pow(x,1/2);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Now, I think that the first while loop told us that x = log(i);

and the second loop is dependent by x and she takes the value of x in each iteration:

x^1/2 + x^1/4 + ••• + x^1/(2^k).

Assume that the second loop stop when x<=2, therefore she run :

(Log(i))^1/(2^k) and after logarithm rules we found that is O(loglog(n))

Comment: The first loop is infinite or never runs.  Are you depending on overflow?

Comment: @afghanimah I think OP means `while(x < i)`.

Comment: @rtx13 if that's the case, I second your answer

Comment: @afghanimah you right, the while loop is (x < i )

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the first loop is `while(x < 1)`.

- First loop is `log(n)`.
- Second loop is `log(log(n))`.

The first loop is dominant, so I would say function `f()` has `log(n)` complexity.

Comment: It doesn’t matter that the second loop dependent by the first loop? And because of that I need to ignore the first loop?

Comment: No, when you add up the complexities, O(logn) + O(loglogn), you can drop O(loglogn) since O(logn) is dominant.  It's like when you have O(n) + O(logn), but you can drop the O(logn).  Try graphing it or counting how many loops each loop does for some inputs to get an understanding.